# Java collections array

Tags: java, arrays, collections

How can I create an array of collection in Java? For example in c++ we have:

```
vector <int> adj[10];
```

and then initialize it using for loop:

```
 cin >> nodes;
 cin >> edges;

 for(int i = 0;i < edges;++i) {
  cin >> x >> y;
  adj[x].push_back(y);                   
  adj[y].push_back(x);                   
}
```

eg:

```
6  
4  
1 2  
2 3  
1 3  
4 5
```

For above input adj will be as follows:

index

```
0   -  
1   -   2   3  
2   -   1   3  
3   -   2   1  
4   -   5  
5   -   4  
6   -  
7   -
```

Comment: Explain yourself ... you want something like this List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();

Comment: I have not understood correctly but you can create like `List<Integer[]> list = new ArrayList<>();` or `Vector<Integer[]> list = new Vector<>();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one java version of your C++ code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<Integer>[] adj = new ArrayList[10];

    for (int i = 0; i < adj.length; i++)
        adj[i] = new ArrayList<>();

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    int nodes = in.nextInt();
    int edges = in.nextInt();

    for (int i = 0; i < edges; ++i) {
        int x = in.nextInt();
        int y = in.nextInt();
        adj[x].add(y);
        adj[y].add(x);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < adj.length; i++)
        System.out.println(adj[i]);

}
```